# Html.BeginForm calls wrong URL with action/1

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my application, I have a form in "/Project/AddFund/1" :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddFund", "Project", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div>
       ...
       <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
}
```

But the html rendered is

```
<form method="post" action="/Project/AddFund/1" novalidate="novalidate"><input type="hidden" value="tM8Gdmnki5mdHiTeuc9m_Ga_LY0hPhuSyAiXs6Ae9yedUn9h-sS-ihBC5Iy3NZtrxBmA7TRbV_jEPgvztuHT3Y6seGZvaLWJUemwg2_5OBR23dVELfJ1wHb0pvAcAOuu0huy_PzAozsQtxZUSBFUQw2" name="__RequestVerificationToken">    <div>
...
</form>
```

In my controllers this method must catch the form submission but it doesn"t work indeed because of the URL with the /id, the controller's code is never called :

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult AddFund(AddFundToProjectViewModel model)
{...}
```

This is the exception:

```
No parameterless constructor defined for this object. [MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.] exception is thrown
```

**As StephenMuecke said in comment, I used a ModelView that has one custom constructor but no default constructor...This was the error!**

How to make this form work with this controller?

Thanks in advance

Comment: add a `string? ID` parameter?

Comment: The route value `1` is added if your GET method is `public ActionResult AddFund(int id)`. It has nothing to do with why your post would not be working.

Comment: Why do I have to do this? I don't want to

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes there is a AddFund(int? id) that render the page that shows the form with viewmodel. Why does it adds the id in the URL? can I override this behaviour?

Comment: So what is your actual problem. Is your model not binding? If so, post your model, GET method and the view. (All that the route parameter is doing is to bind the `ID` property of `AddFundToProjectViewModel` to the value of `1` when you post back)

Comment: Why would you want to override that behavior?

Comment: @Stephen : No parameterless constructor defined for this object. [MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.] exception is thrown

Comment: That because you model `AddFundToProjectViewModel` does not have a parameter-less constructor so the `DefaultModelBinder` throws an exception. You should post the code for your model

Comment: @StephenMuecke I've made an edit of the question

Comment: Does your controller have a parameterless constructor or do you use a DI container for populating the parameters for the contructor?

Comment: Based on your edit, I would recommend just deleting that internal method. That sort of code belongs in the controller, not the view model. But you have shown `CreateProjectViewModel`, not `AddFundToProjectViewModel`

Comment: @StephenMuecke You're right again, I made a custom constructor but no default. I agree with you for the place of that kind of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make a request to an action which has parameters, MVC tries to create those parameters for you, and fill them with data coming from the request body, the route values, the query string... (these are the value providers).

This process is called "model binding". And, if there is a parameter which is an object, like `AddFundToProjectViewModel model`, the first step for the model binding is to create an empty instance of that object, for which it needs a default (parameterless) constructor.

Once the object is built, it tries to set the property values coming from the value providers with the appropriate names.

By default, all classes have a default (parameterless) constructor. But, if you define a constructor with parameters, then, the default constructor is not provided. So, to solve your problem, add a parameterless constructor to your `AddFundToProjectViewModel` class, so that the model binder can do its job.